# Why parquet files created by AWS GLUE in S3 is the same amount of total records in MYSQL table?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, gzip, aws-glue, parquet

I have a table including 13 records, we have a simple GLUE job where it's basically read from table and write to s3 bucket in parquet format as shown in the code in below. When we execute the job, the number of parquet files produced in S3, it's the same as total records we have, so it's writing each row in one parquet file.  I don't understand why this is happening, and why it's not storing all the records just in the same parquet file. Is there any config or setting a parameter that we have missed to do?

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ["JOB_NAME"])
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args["JOB_NAME"], args)

# Script generated for node AWS Glue Data Catalog
AWSGlueDataCatalog_node1671552410216 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
    database="sql_database",
    table_name="ob_cpanel_products",
    transformation_ctx="AWSGlueDataCatalog_node1671552410216",
)

# Script generated for node Change Schema (Apply Mapping)
ChangeSchemaApplyMapping_node1671554868239 = ApplyMapping.apply(
    frame=AWSGlueDataCatalog_node1671552410216,
    mappings=[
        ("productid", "int", "productid", "long"),
        ("productcode", "string", "productcode", "string"),
        ("name", "string", "name", "string"),
        ("quantity", "int", "quantity", "long"),
        ("price", "decimal", "price", "decimal"),
    ],
    transformation_ctx="ChangeSchemaApplyMapping_node1671554868239",
)

# Script generated for node Amazon S3
AmazonS3_node1671554880876 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    frame=ChangeSchemaApplyMapping_node1671554868239,
    connection_type="s3",
    format="glueparquet",
    connection_options={
        "path": "s3://onebox-glue-etl-pre/etl-tpv/output/with_partition/",
        "partitionKeys": [],
    },
    format_options={"compression": "gzip"},
    transformation_ctx="AmazonS3_node1671554880876",
)

job.commit()
```

Comment: did you try any of the methods proposed here: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/glue-job-output-large-files/ ?

Comment: @PandaBlue thanks for the link, I haven't use this. So by default is storing per each record one parquet file?

Comment: I think, that the number of files depends on the number of worker behind the scene, I never tried a glue job on a very small table, I have usually 20 or so produced files by my jobs

Answer (score 0):

you should try to do the repartition before writing that dataframe

```
repartition_dataframe = ChangeSchemaApplyMapping_node1671554868239.repartition(<number of file count>)

#You can use coalesce also instead of repartition
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).